# How to "apt-get remove gcj" without it auto-upgrading on Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to get rid of the crap-tastic gcj package. Trying to remove it produces this from apt:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libhsqldb-java-gcj
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcj-4.4-base libasound2 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libc6-i686
  libdb4.8 libgcj-bc libgcj-common libgcj10 libpython2.6 libreadline6
  libsqlite3-0 libssl0.9.8 locales python-central python2.6 python2.6-minimal
Suggested packages:
  libasound2-plugins glibc-doc libgcj10-dbg libgcj10-awt python2.6-doc
  python2.6-profiler binfmt-support
Recommended packages:
  manpages-dev gcj-4.4-jre-lib
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  java-gcj-compat openoffice.org-gcj
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcj-4.4-base libc-bin libc-dev-bin libdb4.8 libgcj10 libpython2.6
  libreadline6 python2.6 python2.6-minimal
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libasound2 libc6 libc6-dev libc6-i686 libgcj-bc libgcj-common libsqlite3-0
  libssl0.9.8 locales python-central
10 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 2 to remove and 1000 not upgraded.
Need to get 35.4MB of archives.
After this operation, 64.6MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

It looks like its trying to turn around and install the newest version of gcj. I currently have sun-java6-jdk installed.

An suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `aptitude remove gcj` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can try the uninstallation of the package with dpkg:

```
dpkg --purge gcj
```

That won't take care of the dependencies, for good and bad: it will complain if another package depends on gcj, but won't try to install anything else. In the best of cases (no other packages depend on gcj), it will uninstall gcj without complaints.